# Countdown from Google Calendar

Tags: jquery, google-calendar-api, countdown

I'm developing this page: [just a test page yet](http://averty.com.br/dev/treinamentos.php)

where there is a Google Calendar to show the next events. If you scroll down  (under the calendar) you will see a Jquery countdown that shows the up coming time to the next event.

Here is the Jquery code block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $("#days_count")
            .countdown("2018/07/27", function(event) {
              $(this).text(
                event.strftime('%D days')
              );
            });
            $("#hours_count")
            .countdown("2018/07/27", function(event) {
              $(this).text(
                event.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
              );
            });
          </script>
```

I would like to replace the date "2018/07/27" with some code that calls the next event in Google Calendar. Is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You'll need to use the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/). Good luck!

Comment: To help you start with your development, you can visit the [Calendar API documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/). You can refer to the [Events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events) for the references of creation of events and [other methods](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#methods) you needed for your function.

Answer (score 0):

First you need the credentials to access a google calendar resources.

I see that your page is in php, so take a look at [Google Calendar PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php) to see an example of how the api works.

Basically, you need enable the google calendar api in your [google console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) and generate a 'secret_file.json'. With this file you can gain access (read only or reader/writer) to a google calendar.

Once you got this credentials (store it into a file) and you can start working with the [google calendar api](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/).

Specifically, you'll need to call [events list method](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) with the query parameters:

**Required parameters:**

- **calendarId**: Calendar id that you'll show on your web site.

**Optionals parameters:**

- **maxResults**: Set maxResult=1, because you only will need the oncoming event.
- **orderBy**: Set orderBy='startTime' and you'll get a list of incoming events.
- **singleEvents**: Set singleEvents=True, because is needed to sort the events by start date.

**Important:** orderBy='startTime' needs singleEvents equals to True.

> "startTime": Order by the start date/time (ascending). This is only available when querying single events (i.e. the parameter singleEvents is True)

So, you'll get the next json:

```
{
  "kind": "calendar#events",
  "etag": etag,
  "summary": string,
  "description": string,
  "updated": datetime,
  "timeZone": string,
  "accessRole": string,
  "defaultReminders": [
    {
      "method": string,
      "minutes": integer
    }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "nextSyncToken": string,
  "items": [
    events Resource
  ]
}
```

With one single 'item' in the list. This event is the incoming event.

You can check the event resource format [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) to retrieve the 'start.date' or 'start.dateTime' value.

Comment: Thanks JD... I'll try it later and give a feedback if it works.